# Python selenium click on button using find_element_by

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, selenium

I am trying to scrape some speeches from https://www.federalreserve.gov/newsevents/speeches.htm and to do it automatically I need to click on the "Next" button to scrape from all pages.

Unfortunately, I keep getting a `NoSuchElementException`, regardless of the type of `find_element_by` that I use (`by_xpath`, `by_css_selector`, ...). I also tried with `driver.execute_script()` but it did not work.

Here is what I have tried for XPath and CSS selector:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("li.pagination-next:nth-child(11) > a:nth-child(1)")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[4]/ul[1]/li[11]/a')
```

Here is the HTML code of the button:

```
<li ng-if="::directionLinks" ng-class="{disabled: noNext()||ngDisabled}" class="pagination-next ng-scope">
<a href="" ng-click="selectPage(page + 1, $event)" ng-disabled="noNext()||ngDisabled" uib-tabindex-toggle="" class="ng-binding">Next</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Perhaps the CSS selector isn't quite right? There is an easier way to hit a button like that in selenium: `driver.find_element_by_link_text('Next')` https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the element by using the following code:
I have used the button's text in the xpath to find it and have used explicit wait so that the script waits until the element is present on the page.

```
next_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Next']")))
next_button.click()
```

You need to add the following imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I tried it but it times out without finding the button